# Error on some deleted questions that have been migrated away

Tags: bug, migration, deleted-questions

I am unable to view some questions that have been migrated away and subsequently deleted. I'm talking about the stub left behind by migration, which is automatically deleted after 30 days. I do have the privilege to view deleted posts. For example, on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away):

- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/does-e-really-equal-mc2?noredirect=1 (deleted by me) works
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/why-do-we-capitalize-all-race-names-but-our-own?noredirect=1 redirects me to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/6680/why-do-we-capitalize-all-race-names-but-our-own

This doesn't seem to be related to my having initiated the migration: I can view [1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/does-e-really-equal-mc2?noredirect=1) (migrated by DampeS8N, deleted by me) and [2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31788/how-much-would-a-third-season-of-sgu-cost-to-produce?noredirect=1) (migrated by me, deleted by Community) but cannot view [3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/is-there-a-specific-reason-why-karlsson-is-rather-overweight?noredirect=1), [4](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8865/why-didnt-sherlock-holmes-investigate-the-events-surrounding-irene-adler?noredirect=1), [5](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7274/why-did-the-girl-try-to-kill-herself-in-the-2009-sherlock-holmes-film?noredirect=1), [6](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9708/hacking-computers-scifi-or-reality?noredirect=1), [7](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24292/star-wars-where-science-meets-imagination-how-much-time-to-allow?noredirect=1), …

[Kevin remarks](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2936/error-on-some-deleted-questions-that-have-been-migrated-away/2938#2938) that the posts I can't view as a 10k user visible to mods, and indicated as “deleted” with no other indication. I can view the posts that are marked as “deleted by <user>” (whether the user is Community or a real user).

I was able to reproduce the issue on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away) where I have the 10k privileges but have never been a mod: I get the “something bad happened” page for [U-1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53388/how-do-i-recover-an-unregistered-username?noredirect=1), [U-2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52957/arm-kernel-memory-layout?noredirect=1), [U-3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52543/how-to-remove-masking-bit-from-sigcgt-in-the-status-file-under-proc-pid?noredirect=1), … but I see the deleted stub for [U+1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53515/partitioning-problem-windows-occupies-2-partitions?noredirect=1), [U+2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53860/working-with-this-arduino-board?noredirect=1), [U+3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55097/how-to-use-malloc-stats-in-c-program-on-linux?noredirect=1), … I also get the error page for [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816449/modify-dns-cache-other-than-hosts-file?noredirect=1), … On SO the threshold date is: [migrated 2012-11-01 21:10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179162/wordpress-widget-constantly-switching?noredirect=1) ok, [migrated 2012-11-01 20:38](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002602/how-do-i-move-apache-tomcats-root-directory-on-freebsd?noredirect=1) → [oops](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/13002602/how-do-i-move-apache-tomcats-root-directory-on-freebsd).

So it seems that older migrations, before 2012-11-01, that were automatically deleted, left a stub that triggers a server-side error when viewed by 10k non-mods.

Answer (score 4):

Very old questions migrated and auto-deleted are marked simply as "deleted," without specifying who deleted them. Then some time between [Nov 10, 2012](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24292/3267) and [Jan 12, 2013](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/27894/3267), automatically deleted migrations began being attributed as "deleted by Community♦". You (and any 10k) can see questions marked as deleted by a user (including Community♦) whether before or after this date.  However, all 10k non-mods see an error page when trying to view any unattributed deletion (I confirmed on Unix.SE).

This is clearly a bug.

Comment: I looked on U&L too, and found that the earliest migrated stub I can see is http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53515/partitioning-problem-windows-occupies-2-partitions?noredirect=1. Given that U&L migrates out fairly often this should give a precise indication of the threshold date.

Answer (score 1):

Gilles, I am able to view both of your bullet pointed examples, and every other one you list.

Looking at the revisions here is the order of operations:

1. **Closed** (DampeS8N), **Locked** (Community♦), **Migrated** (DampeS8N), **Deleted** (Gilles).
2. **Closed** (*other users*, Gilles), **Migrated** (*other users*, Gilles), **Locked** (Community♦), **Deleted** (Community♦).
3. **Closed** (Gilles), **Locked**(Community♦), **Migrated** (Gilles)
4. **Closed**(*other users*, Gilles), **Locked** (Community♦), **Migrated**(*other users* Gilles)
5. **Closed**(*other users*, Gilles), **Migrated** (*other users*, Gilles), **Locked** (Community♦)
6. **Closed** (Gilles), **Migrated** (Gilles), **Locked** (Community♦)
7. **Closed** (Moderator), **Migrated** (Moderator), **Locked** (Community♦)

There's a clear pattern that seems to suggest that if it isn't explicitly deleted, it might be come invisible to high-rep non-mods.

<strike>Beyond that I don't know any more.</strike>

Beyond the above conclusion, I have to ask, do you know which of these came before/after you were de-modded? It might be that you *shouldn't* be able to see 1,2 instead of the other way round, but you can as those were mod-closes, not VtC closes.

Alternatively, like Kevin says below:

> [It] definitely appears to be that you can see mod-deleted and those marked "deleted by Community♦" but not auto-deleted ones just marked "deleted" without attribution.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. [2](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31788/how-much-would-a-third-season-of-sgu-cost-to-produce?noredirect=1) was deleted by Community. Do you see a pattern in the way I've interacted with the question? It could be a specific bug that only affects former mods…

Comment: I will have to go back and check later, but I believe that they were all community locked/deleted. I didn't see any other patterns pertaining to you. But like I said I will be back later to check

Comment: @Gilles definitely appears to be that you can see mod-deleted and those marked "deleted by Community♦" but not auto-deleted ones just marked "deleted" without attribution.